# Difficult closing the .exe process in excel

Tags: vba, excel, taskmanager

I'm building a MS-Excel extract from a VB6 application. I'm having a very difficult time getting rid of the .exe process for excel. I generate an extract and save it to C: drive. I don't open it or anything, yet it's still visible in the Task Manager under Processes. Here is how I declare and close all excel components.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets.Add
```

This I do all the way at the end of the procedure

```
Xlbook.close
Set xlSheetWeek = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Why is the process still working even though I do all the xlbook.close and Don't have excel open. It shouldn't be showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the Quit() method on your Excel.Application object (xlApp), https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839269.aspx:

```
xlApp.Quit()
```

Comment: Clear all existing Excel processes from memory and try it again. Make sure that you close everything you open in reverse order as part of your clean up process, prior to setting your object variables to Nothing.

Comment: Cool! Glad to be of assistance :)

Comment: I could swear I tried xlapp.quit before. I was using the code from another report and set my xlSheetXX = nothing, except it wasn't the name of my sheet. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @FatBoySlim7!

Comment: Done, I wanted to mark it completed yesterday right after he posted it, however, couldn't do it for 15 minutes and I left work.

Answer (score -1):

You can get crazy and

```
sKill = "TASKKILL /F /IM excel.exe"
Shell sKill, vbHide
```